# CSS text-shadow that works on different font-sizes

Tags: css

I have the following CSS on my

```
h2 {
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 6px 0 #E5E5E5
}
```

The problem is that this looks good only on some font-sizes, in others it looks really bad. If the font is really big the shadow is barely noticeable, if the font is too small the shadow makes the text unreadable. In my webpage the font of this particular element changes sizes dynamically. It can be as small as 10px and as big as 200px.

For some reason setting the shadow position in % do not work, one would hope it would take a % of the font-size attribute.

So I'm asking here if there is any way to make text-shadow works on fonts that changes size using CSS alone. I'm hoping for a solution that doesn't use javascript.

Comment: how do you change the font-size? resizing the screen?

Comment: I change it using javascript. I get the number of characters of the h2 element and make it fit as big as possible on his parent. So if the text is only one or two characters long the font-size will be pretty big.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `em` instead of `px` in the `text-shadow` and `em` relates to the actual set size of the typeface.

- [Examples on w3.org](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/text-shadow.en.html)
- [Understanding `em`](http://v1.jontangerine.com/log/2007/09/the-incredible-em-and-elastic-layouts-with-css)

Comment: That works, I don't know why I haven't thought about using ems before.

Answer (score 1):

see

http://rcljr.com/rcl/tests/TextShadow%20Supreme/index.html

for a text shadow formatter